# I'm trying to work with the CoreBluetooth module, but part of my code doesn't run

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I'm attempting to use my Mac as a bluetooth peripheral using the `CoreBluetooth` module. I've looked at the docs and various examples of it, but my code still doesn't work. I put print statements throughout it, and for some reason the only print statements which show up in my output are "1" and "1.5". This is in an XCode 11.6 playground running on Mac OS Catalina 10.15.6, if that helps.

```sqift
import AppKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import CoreBluetooth

print("1")
let myCBUUID = CBUUID(string:"2FC62EDD-EFED-457A-A88E-6E9BC1B8D7AF")
let properties: CBCharacteristicProperties = [.notify, .read, .write]
let permissions: CBAttributePermissions = [.readable, .writeable]
let characteristic = CBMutableCharacteristic(type:myCBUUID,properties: properties, value:nil, permissions: permissions)
let myCBService = CBMutableService(type:myCBUUID,primary: true)
myCBService.characteristics = [characteristic]
print("1.5")
class Peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, CBPeripheralManagerDelegate
{
    var peripheralManager : CBPeripheralManager!
    convenience init(delegate: CBPeripheralManagerDelegate?,
                     queue: DispatchQueue?){
        print("1.75")
        self.init()
        peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: [CBPeripheralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: true])
        peripheralManager.add(myCBService)
    }
    func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager)
    {
        print("2")
        print("state: \(peripheral.state)")
    }
    func Advertise(){
        print("hello its me")
        peripheralManager.startAdvertising([CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey : "My Peripheral", CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey : myCBUUID])
    }
    func peripheralManagerDidStartAdvertising(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, error: NSError?)
    {
        if let error = error
        {
            print("Failed due to error: \(error)")
            return
        }
        print("Success")
    }
}

let myPeripheral = Peripheral.init()
myPeripheral.Advertise()
```

(this is my first time posting, sorry if i messed anything up and feel free to make suggestions in the comments if i left something out)

Comment: You need to actually create an instance of `Peripheral` and you need to add an initialiser that creates your `CBPeripheralManager`

Comment: iOS Smulators do not work with Bluetooth, only real iPhones. So I'm not sure how it will work on playground. Try to create project, with some application and test it

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for the help, Paul! Would I be able to create an instance of Peripheral just by running `let myPeripheral = Peripheral.init()` ? Also, how can I initialize CBPeripheralManager?

Comment: @Володимир A macOS playground running on a Mac will support Bluetooth. There is nothing in the question to indicate that iOS is involved.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheralmanager/1393299-init

Comment: @Paulw11. Thanks for the reply! I looked at the docs but I was kind of confused. It says that for the init() method of the Peripheral class, one of the arguments is a CBPeripheralManagerDelegate, but I'm not sure how to initiate one of those since it's a protocol? I tried adding `let myPeripheral = Peripheral.init(delegate: CBPeripheralManagerDelegate?,
queue: nil)` but it gives me an error, saying "Cannot convert value of type 'CBPeripheralManagerDelegate?.Type' to expected argument type 'CBPeripheralManagerDelegate?'" What am I not understanding?

Comment: Your `Peripheral` class already conforms to that protocol so you can just pass `self` as the delegate

Comment: @Paulw11 How can I instantiate my Peripheral class from within my Peripheral class?     Edit: Am I not already creating a CBPeripheralManager on line 25 with `peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: [CBPeripheralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: true])` ?

Comment: I just updated my post to reflect the changes that I've made so far. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Update: I think I now understand that I needed to declare an init() method inside of my Peripheral class. The init method runs and fires the print() statement within it, however it runs infinitely as soon as I run my code.